System error during disk write
I have an Intel Core i7 machine with a Gigabyte B560M cheap motherboard with two NVME modules and a large SATA HDD. Whenever I try to copy large directories, I get the error shown in the attached image, and then most disk IO operations freeze, and often, the OS freezes. Any combination of source and destination drives causes this error.
Can anyone help me figure out what is causing this error? This machine is kept in a data centre, and physical access has time restrictions. If I can save some time identifying the cause, it would help a lot.


That's a stack dump but the information we need is missing off the top of the screen. What does dmesg report? (As text please, not as a screenshot.)

@ChrisDavies getting text might be hard for someone with no working storage at that point :)  But I agree: while we see in the backtrace here that this is a writeback queue (which might point to a filesystem bug), it's only the backtrace of some process being forcibly ended. The backtrace above would help us more! And if possible, yes, copy and paste as text, please. Please also tell us about your linux kernel version (uname -r). We'll also need the output of lsblk, because this seems to be related to a dm device.

@MarcusMüller I didn't see "no working storage", I saw "Whenever I try to copy large directories, I get the error shown […] and then most disk IO operations freeze". I was assuming that the relatively small requirement for dmesg or at least the OS/Distribution equivalent to tail /var/log/kern.log might show something. (It does depend on whether the in-OS disk cache gets written out, of course, but there's usually something to start. Particularly if the OS is running off one/both of the NVMe disks.)

you're right, @ChrisDavies, but either way, the ball is very much in the asker's field currently.
